# why delete check need if write permission is not exist

Tags: c, unix

I am practicing unix system
and book said

> when you use unlink to delete file check write permission before delete
> and if not permission exist check again

```c
if (access(argv[1], W_OK) == -1) {
    /*
    ~~~~~
     check code which user really want to delete file
    if user say "no" process exit 
    */
    if (unlink(argv[1]) == -1) {
      perror("unlink failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
} else {
    if (unlink(argv[1]) == -1) {
      perror("unlink failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
}
```

and also when i use 'rm' similar thins happen

> touch test
> chmod 400 test
> rm test
> override r--------  user/user for test?

if i insert no system don't delete and say yes delete.

why i need that? why i need to be careful?

Comment: You can delete the file if you have write access to the *directory*. Checking write access to the file is just some extra application semantic they have dreamed up. Should be explained in the text.

Comment: Please do not use `access()` this way: this is NOT a handy "does the file exist?" kind of function, but is meant for setuid/setgid programs to test whether the *underlying* user would have permissions.  Using `access()` incorrectly means your program works OK in most cases but will fail in crazy ways if used in setuid or setgid environment.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: this is a pretty special case, and as OP says it's based on the way `rm` is actually implemented. The check is not used to decide whether to delete the file; it's used to double check with the user before they delete a read-only file.

Comment: See step 3 in the Posix spec for `rm` which requires this check. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html#tag_20_111

Comment: @rici: I understand that the `rm` command has to do some checking as noted, but the use of `access()` is not doing that. It's considering the *real* uid/gid instead of the *effective* uid/gid, and this makes the system call useful only in the context of a setuid/setgid program. To make the test that `rm` requires, you have to use something like `stat()` and fool with the permission bits.  But `access()` is wrong for this.

Comment: @SteveFriedl: I get the problem with `access` but I'm not convinced that `eaccess` is ideal, either. (Actually, Gnu coreutils uses the newer `faccessat` with the `AT_EACCESS` flag to test the effective uid, rather than depend on a non-standard interface.) FreeBSD, at least the last time I used it, uses `access`. These have the same effect in the common interactive shell use case, where real and effective are the same. But in a sudo shell, Linux rm deletes anything without a blink, while FreeBSD still warns you. And I've been happier with the latter...

Comment: ...but of course it's possible that I'm just more careless than average, and shouldn't be allowed near a shell without a safety harness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful because it's common to think that making files read-only protects them. So if I accidentally attempt to delete a read-only file, I might expect the system to save me from my mistake. But it won't, because the permissions on the file are irrelevant; the delete will succeed if the user has write permission on the *directory*.

Probably all of us who have been using Unix for some time have been saved more than once by this particular check. But if you believe that you and all of the future users of your software never make mistakes, feel free to omit the check.

However, consider that the [Posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html#tag_20_111)  *requires* this test in  the `rm` command:

> If *file* is not of type directory, the **-f** option is not specified, and either the permissions of *file* do not permit writing and the standard input is a terminal or the **-i** option is specified, *rm* shall write a prompt to the standard error and read a line from the standard input. If the response is not affirmative, *rm* shall do nothing more with the current file and go on to any remaining files.

---

#### Note:

There's a long comment thread about the advisability of using `access` to do this check; I haven't copied it here because it doesn't affect the answer to the question "Why should I be careful", and the optimal implementation of being careful is perhaps subject to opinion. But I might try to resume it later.